# IncompatibleClassChangeError when calling getSplit hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.0.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera

I'm using the Cloudera-VM.  Hadoop version: Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.0.0.

I have written an inputFileFormat, when the client calls the getSplits method I get an exception:

```
IncompatibleClassChangeError found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext expecting
```

I'm using the classes from the mapreduce package not mapred.

However when I look at the stacktrace I see that somewhere along the line the library changes to mapred:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at com.hadoopApp.DataGeneratorFileInput.getSplits(DataGeneratorFileInput.java:27)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:945)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:596)
    at com.hadoopApp.HBaseApp.generateData(HBaseApp.java:54)
    at com.hadoopApp.HBaseApp.run(HBaseApp.java:24)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.hadoopApp.HBaseApp.main(HBaseApp.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Not sure if this helps, but i'm using this in my maven pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**solved it not sure why**
changed my pom to this and started working - not sure why it solved it though - your input is appreciated it:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-cdh4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-cdh4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

How can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've bumped into the same problem when using Hipi on cdh4.2.0.

The problem is caused by incompatibilities between Hadoop versions (jobs build with Hadoop 1 may not work on Hadoop 2). Initially you were building the job with Hadoop v1 and running it on Hadoop 2.0.0 environment (cloudera uses Hadoop 2.0.0).

Fortunately, hadoop 1.x API is fully supported in Hadoop 2.x, so rebuilding the job with newer version of hadoop helps.

Comment: Can you temme how to build my M/R program in MR-v2 . Actually for compiling in MR-v1 i have been using "hadoop-core.jar" likewise what is for MR-v2 . Im using windows machine